# android simulator does not recognize .mobile.cshtml page

Tags: model-view-controller

I have different views for desktop and mobile browsers, and for that I have created seperate _Layout.mobile.cshtml, and [_ViewName].mobile.cshtml views.

The problem is that when I run the application in android simulator it shows desktop pages only. Why it does not recognize _Layout.mobile.cshtml and relevant view pages? Is there any code that needs to be written?

Any help on this much appreciated.